# Decrypting password in PHP

Tags: php, function, encryption, output, mcrypt

I have encrypted username and password in php using `crypt` function. How can I decrypt that username and password?

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); 
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); 
$key = "This is a very secret key"; 
$text = "Welcome to the system."; 
echo strlen($text) . "\n";
```

This doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow. If you want help, we need to see some code :) Why not paste your code and let us examine it?

Comment: This question seems a bit dodgy to me - sounds like you're trying to obtain someone else's credentials without their permission.

Comment: Could be perfectly legit too. First time I started storing encrypted passwords in a database I didn't understand how to check if the user inputed the correct one at login :P. I've learned quite a bit since then...

Comment: xil3 it must not be something malicious. Why not wait and see what it will be

Comment: FYI-I am working on building authentication system in PHP. I am not trying to acquire anyones login credentials. I was playing with many functions like base_64,md5,crypt etc. Just wanted to know which one is most secure and i found crypt to be most helpful but could not decrypt it.

Comment: @ads I see that you're using the first example from [the `mcrypt_encrypt()` man page](http://us3.php.net/mcrypt_encrypt). First, check to make sure you have the mcrypt extension enabled. If you do, the code you shared should only print a number. See the rest of that example to generate the encrypted string into `$crypttext`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. The [`crypt()` function](http://php.net/crypt) is a one-way hashing function.

If you're using a different function that does perform encryption (such as [`mcrypt_encrypt()`](http://php.net/mcrypt_encrypt)), please share which.

Comment: $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "This is a very secret key";
    $text = "Welcome to the system.";
    echo strlen($text) . "\n";This doesn't print anything. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, thank you. This is useful information that belongs with the question, so please edit your original question to add it.

Comment: What is the error in my code?

Comment: @ads See my comment to the question above.

Comment: I am not storing encrypted password in DB. I have to pass the encrypted username from main authentication system to a sub portal and allow the user access to that portal. SO i plan to descrypt the username in sub portal. I cannot use mcrypt_encrypt as the code i posted is not working.

Comment: @ads We're trying to figure out _why_ it is not working. Did you check that the mcrypt extension is enabled in PHP?

Comment: i did not find the mycrypt.so extension in my php.ini file. Can i add it?

Comment: @ads Perhaps, but mcrypt might be compiled into the PHP binary itself. Check if it's enabled with `phpinfo()`. If it isn't, then figure out how to enable it.

Answer (score 5):

From the PHP documentation for [`crypt()`](https://www.php.net/crypt#refsect1-function.crypt-notes):

> Note: There is no decrypt function, since crypt() uses a one-way algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

`crypt()` is a one-way encryption on PHP. You can't decrypt it back.

If you want to use encryption-decryption functions, check this [`PHP manual`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)

Answer (score 1):

You don't.
You would verify a users credentials against the hash version you have stored.
http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

So if a user signs up you hash their password so no one, not even you knows what it is.  This is a security measure.  When a user tries to log in to your site, you take their password call `crypt()` on it again and verify that entry in your storage.

Comment: What is the error in my code?